# TypeScript: Extract string literal as function param

Tags: typescript, meteor, typescript-typings, string-literals

I am playing around with meteor.js and TypeScript and trying to make meteor methods that are strongly typed.

For this I created a file containing type definitions for my methods like so:

```
export interface ClientWithSecret {
    id: string;
    secret: string;
}

export interface MeteorMethod {
    name: string;
    args: any[];
    return: any;
}

export interface NewGameMethod extends MeteorMethod {
    name: "newGame";
    args: [auth: ClientWithSecret];
    return: string;
}

export interface NewClientMethod extends MeteorMethod {
    name: "newClient";
    args: [];
    return: ClientWithSecret;
}

export interface LoginMethod extends MeteorMethod {
    name: "login";
    args: [auth: ClientWithSecret];
    return: true | ClientWithSecret;
}

export type ValidMethods = NewGameMethod | NewClientMethod | LoginMethod;
```

Now I am trying to create a method that wraps the normal meteor method (which use callbacks...) to a function returning a promise like this:

```
export function meteorCallAsync<T extends MeteorMethod>(methodName: T["name"], args: T["args"]): Promise<T["return"]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Meteor.call(methodName, ...args, (error: Meteor.Error, result: T["return"]) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

This seems to be working like a charm. I can await a meteor method like that

```
const retVal = await meteorCallAsync<NewGameMethod>("newGame", [getClientWithSecret()]);
```

and TypeScript actually checks if the string `"newGame"` is equal to the string literal defined as the name of `NewGameMethod`. Perfect, but I have two questions, since I'm new to TypeScript:

- Is it possible to omit the first parameter to `meteorCallAsync` altogether and let the TypeScript compiler fill it in? I am already defining the type as a generic, so the compiler does have the necessary information to fill this in but I have no idea if this is supported in TypeScript
- Is there a way to define the `MeteorMethod` interface as some kind of abstract interface which cannot be instantiated? Would the `ValidMethods` actually be a more appropriate type for `meteorCallAsync<T extends ValidMethods>` and is there a way for me to enforce that each method actually has to have a `name`, `args`, and `return`?

EDIT:
I have added my implementation of the `newGame` method below. The problem is that I have no idea how to tell TypeScript that `Meteor.call(name, ...args, (error, result)=>{})` actually calls the function defined in `Meteor.methods`

```
Meteor.methods({
    // create a new game
    newGame(auth: ClientWithSecret) {
        if (!isValidClient(auth)) {
            console.error(`client invalid ${auth.id}`);
            return;
        }
        let randomId,
            newIdFound = false;
        while (!newIdFound) {
            randomId = Random.id();
            const game = GamesCollection.findOne({ _id: randomId });
            if (!game) {
                newIdFound = true;
            }
        }
        GamesCollection.insert({
            _id: randomId,
            hostId: auth.id,
            clientIds: [auth.id],
            players: [],
            createdAt: new Date(Date.now()),
        });
        return randomId;
    },
    newClient(): ClientWithSecret {
        //implementation
    },
    login(auth: ClientWithSecret): true | ClientWithSecret {
        // returns true if login successful, new ClientWithSecret if credentials invalid
    },
});
```

Comment: Your interfaces aren't needed because you can use [ReturnType<T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and [Parameters<T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to derive the `args` and `return` from the type of the function.  You just need to know the association from method name to method type.  You could create an interface where the keys are the names and the values are the methods, but that might already exist in the Meteor typings. I will look at the Meteor package types so I can give you a solid answer.

Comment: Ok so [`Meteor.call`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b692ee5989ae2049a129f337f50f228d5ebe9666/types/meteor/meteor.d.ts#L76) is defined in a very loose and unhelpful way `function call(name: string, ...args: any[]): any;`  It seems like you define the methods with [`Meteor.methods()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html) so we can tap into that to get the types for your app's methods.

Comment: I have added my implementation of the newGame() meteor method and an explanation why I am trying to define this with my own types, which hopefully makes sense. If there are more advanced methods of directly coupling `Meteor.call` to the methods without my workaround I would of course be happy to hear about them.

Comment: You can look into declaration merging.  I think what you are doing is good, but you can do it with less TS code.  I am working on an answer for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Background

You shouldn't have to type out interfaces for every function because that information already exists somewhere in your code base.  If you know they type of the function itself then you can use [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to derive the types for the args and the return from the type of the function.  The part that we are missing here is the association between the function names and the function types.

I'm not familiar with Meteor so I've had to look at the docs to see how this works.  It turns out that the types are very loosely defined.

[`Meteor.call()`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b692ee5989ae2049a129f337f50f228d5ebe9666/types/meteor/meteor.d.ts#L76) allows you to pass any function name with any arguments.

```
function call(name: string, ...args: any[]): any;
```

It is smart to create a wrapper around this function like you are doing here.  You will get better type-safety and better autocomplete support. You could possibly use declaration merging to augment the package types, but wrapping it is easier to implement.

The callable function names get defined by calling [`Meteor.methods()`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b692ee5989ae2049a129f337f50f228d5ebe9666/types/meteor/meteor.d.ts#L74) with a dictionary object of methods.

```
function methods(methods: {[key: string]: (this: MethodThisType, ...args: any[]) => any}): void;
```

#### Solution

We want to get the type of your specific dictionary.  We will use an intermediate variable rather than defining the methods inside of `Meteor.methods()` so that we can use `typeof` on that variable to get your dictionary type.

```
// define the methods
const myMethods = {
  newGame(auth: ClientWithSecret) {
....
}

// set the methods on Meteor
Meteor.methods(myMethods);

// get the type
type MyMeteorMethods = typeof myMethods;
```

We then use that `MyMeteorMethods` type to annotate your `meteorCallAsync` function.

```
export function meteorCallAsync<T extends keyof MyMeteorMethods>(
  methodName: T, 
  ...args: Parameters<MyMeteorMethods[T]>
): Promise<ReturnType<MyMeteorMethods[T]>> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Meteor.call(methodName, ...args, (error: Meteor.Error, result: ReturnType<MyMeteorMethods[T]>) => {
          if (error) {
              reject(error);
          }
          resolve(result);
      });
  });
}
```

- `T` is the method name, which must be a key on your dictionary.
- `MyMeteorMethods[T]` is type for the method.
- Your `args` match the parameters of the method.  I changed `args` to `...args` so that you can pass arguments individually instead of in an array.
- Your return type is a `Promise` of the method's return type.

Now when you call the function you don't need to set any types.  Typescript can infer the correct types based on the `methodName`.  You get errors where you want them and no errors where you don't.

```
const x = async () => {

  // ok to call with the correct arguments
  const retVal1 = await meteorCallAsync("newGame", getClientWithSecret());
  
  // error if required arguments are missing
  // 'Arguments for the rest parameter 'args' were not provided.'
  const retVal2 = await meteorCallAsync("newGame");

  // ok to call with no arguments if the method doesn't require any
  const retVal3 = await meteorCallAsync("newClient");

  // error if calling an invalid method name
  // 'Argument of type '"invalidFunc"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"newGame" | "newClient" | "login"''
  const retVal4 = await meteorCallAsync("invalidFunc");
}
```

#### Advanced

If you want to make use of `this` inside of any methods in your methods object, that requires some finessing.  Some of the types that we want to use here (such as `MethodThisType`) aren't exported so we need to work backwards to get them.

```
type MeteorMethodDict = Parameters<typeof Meteor.methods>[0]
```

This gives us the type for that method dictionary object where each entry is a function with a `this` type of `MethodThisType`.

We want to make sure that your methods extend the `MeteorMethodDict` type without widening the type and losing information about your specific methods.  So we can create the methods through an identity function that enforces the type.

```
const makeMethods = <T extends MeteorMethodDict>(methods: T): T => methods;
```

Now you can use `this` inside any of the methods and it will have the correct type.

```
const myMethods = makeMethods({
  newGame(auth: ClientWithSecret) {
    const userId = this.userId;
...
```

The type that we get from `type MyMeteorMethods = typeof myMethods` will include the `this` type whether you use it or not.

```
type MyMeteorMethods = {
    newGame(this: Meteor.MethodThisType, auth: ClientWithSecret): any;
    newClient(this: Meteor.MethodThisType): ClientWithSecret;
    login(this: Meteor.MethodThisType, auth: ClientWithSecret): true | ClientWithSecret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I will try this out tomorrow. One mental block that I had was "I don't want the client to know the entire implementation of a method" but that was because I had not internalized that nothing of the TS specific stuff will actually land in the source code.